# unstable_createResource invalidation in react-cache/suspense

Tags: reactjs, invalidation, react-cache

How do I invalidate a resource created by `react-cache`?

I can fetch data from API:

```
const FooResource = createResource(id => fetch(`/foo/${id}`)); // return a promise, or async/await

// inside render...
const fooResponse = FooResource.read(id); // suspends if not in cache; renders if in cache
return <div> {fooResponse} </div>;
```

However, when I update the data on the backend I am unable to refetch the data on the frontend.

This is the only somehow official documentation that I was able to find: https://github.com/sw-yx/fresh-concurrent-react/blob/master/apis/react-cache.md

Is there some undocumented API that I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general — **you can't, and this is why it's "unstable". Don't use it for anything except demos and tinkering.** We'll likely replace the whole thing with a different API.

Comment: Thank you, of course, I am just playing around with the new API. I will patiently wait for the implementation. 

Answer (score 1):

As of now `react-cache` uses [LRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least_recently_used_(LRU)) (*least recently used*) caching policy. By this policy, the least recently used entries are invalidated first.

The size of the cache can be set using function [`unstable_setGlobalCacheLimit`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/19ef0ec116a2c5fd1a8dc86d38c2185d62abc6a1/packages/react-cache/src/ReactCache.js#L186).

I couldn't find a function for explicit cache invalidation in [the project](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-cache). I also think that it is good news, 'cause [dealing with cache](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) is generally a hassle. It seems like LRU is going to make it easier for most React users.

Manual cache control might find its way in the future versions of `react-cache` as more developers embrace the technology and discover new use cases that need a custom approach, but I doubt it's something one should consider for now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot more control over the cache is required using `react-cache`. It seems it is written considering only client-side rendering(though it works on both csr and ssr).

On the server, there are high chances that only a few specific API's need to be cached for a given interval. All user-specific API's or data should not be cached in react-cache.

react-cache should give control to differentiate caching behavior on both client and server as both environments have completely different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `react-cache` source code doesn't point to any `invalidation` capability. It makes sense to need `invalidation`, to update the results for example after you've added a new comment or post, as well as use `suspense` with `post/put/delete` requests,  which should not be `cached` by default in the first place.